# c++ code error. What am i doing wrong here?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, I'm creating a function that breaks down an ip address and puts the values between "." into an array. I get this error:

```
Assigning to 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type' (aka 'char') from incompatible type 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
//  main.cpp
//  Subnet calculator

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string ip2arr(string ehh, string arr);

int main(void){

}

string ip2arr(string ehh, string arr){
    ehh+=".";
    int list_counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0, f = 0; i < ehh.length(); i++) {
        if (ehh[i] == '.') {
            arr[list_counter] = ehh.substr(f,i-1-f+1);
            list_counter++;
            f = i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: arr[list_counter] = ehh.substr(f,i-1-f+1);

Comment: 'arr' is a string, not an array of strings. arra[list_counter] is likely issue

Comment: `string::substr`returns a `std::string` and you are assigning it to a `char&` through `operator[]`

Comment: Your missing the `#include <string>` header.

Comment: Fixed it, Thanks guys!! (the array was just a string)

Comment: Consider passing the arguments by reference so that a *copy* is not passed to the function.

Comment: Also, you are not returning anything, yet your function says it returns a `std::string`.  Thus calling this function leads to undefined behavior due to a lack of a return value.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews bad advise, function returns a string (actually it misses return statement)

Comment: You should assign `ehh.length()` to a constant temporary variable so that you are not calling the `length()` function every iteration.  The length of `ehh` is not changing within the loop.

Comment: @Slava, the first statement is `ehh+=".";`, which implies that the original string is being modified (at least that could be one understanding).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews bad advise again, it is perfectly fine to call `std::string::length()` in a loop - it has constant complexity.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews OP adds '.' to that string so his algo would work with it, he has no intention to return that.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" it is easier to say what you are doing right rather than what you are doing wrong here.

Comment: @yosemite The best advice I can give is: Learn how to decipher those kind of _cryptic_ error messages, or use a compiler that provides better ones.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to occur on the line

```
arr[list_counter] = ehh.substr(f,i-1-f+1);
```

Here, `arr` is a string, and so `arr[list_counter]` is a single character. But you are attempting to assign to it the result of `ehh.substr(f,i-1-f+1)` which is a string.

I cannot advise you how to fix this because I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Note that there is another issue: you are attempting to assign a value to a parameter which is passed into the function by value. This will not affect the variable's value in the calling function. Most likely you should build up a result in the function and `return` a value rather than change its parameter's value.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

Oh well, let's start

1. Your code is using `std::string` but you are missing `#include <string>` directive
2. Your function returns `std::string` but there is no return statement
3. You pass parameter `arr` but do not use it but trying to assign values to it
4. You access elements in `arr` without checking that index is valid
5. You are trying to assign `std::string` to lvalue of type `char`
6. This is not error, but you would get warning of comparing `signed int i` with unsigned value that `std::string::length()` returns

I hope I did not miss anything

Comment: Nitpicking, but you could also mention the use of post increment rather than preincrement (doesn't matter for `int`s but does matter for some custom types, so one may as well get into the good pre-inc habit . You could also mention that the input strings are passed by value rather than as `const&` or `string_view`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl passing first argument by value in this case is fine as OP modifies it (if it is good modifying it to algo to work is different question). Preincrement 
 vspost increment would be really nitpicking in this case